# Different code coverage from Jacoco and Intellij

Tags: java, unit-testing, gradle, intellij-idea, jacoco

I am trying to integrate `Jacoco` in my project. 
I have a simple class

```
package in.ashwanik.project;

import java.util.Objects;

public class ArithmeticOperations {

    public int add(Integer a, Integer b) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(a);
        Objects.requireNonNull(b);
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

And the corresponding test cases

```
package in.ashwanik.project;

import org.junit.Test;

public class ArithmeticOperationsTest {

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testAddA() {
        ArithmeticOperations entity = new ArithmeticOperations();
        entity.add(null, 1);
    }

    @Test(expected = NullPointerException.class)
    public void testAddB() {
        ArithmeticOperations entity = new ArithmeticOperations();
        entity.add(1, null);
    }
}
```

***I have intentionally left out the test case which passes not null parameters.***

Command to run `Jacoco` tests.

```
./gradlew clean build test jacocoTestReport
```

When I run `Jacoco` on this project, the code coverage is only 40%.

[image]

However, when I run IntelliJ code coverage, I get 75%

[image]

Test cases run
[image]

I am not sure why this discrepancy is there?

**How can I have the same coverage from both the tools?**

Comment: it seems that Jacoco is running the first test only

Comment: @FranMontero Update the question. I think Jacoco runs all the tests